# Multiply numbers in mixed string

Tags: php, replace, numbers

My trouble is to multiply numbers in string that contains various characters.

*For example,*

Input:

```
$k     = 2;    
$input = '<div style="padding:10px 15px; font-size:1em ;height:2%;"></div>';
```

Output:

```
<div style="padding:20px 30px; font-size:2em ;height:4%;"></div>
```

*Edit*

`$k` can be any whole number (0-9). All numbers from `$input` string are multiplied by `$k`.

Comment: `$k` can be any whole number (0-9), and it's multiplying all numbers in `$input` string

Comment: @enloz: You should explain that in your question; at present, it doesn't say anything at all about your functional requirements.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback):

```
$input = '<div style="padding:10px 15px; font-size:1em ;height:2%;"></div>';
$output = preg_replace_callback('/([0-9]+)\s*(px|em|%)/i', function($matches){
   $k = 2;
   return ($matches[1] * $k).$matches[2];
}, $input);
```

The above only replace numbers followed by `px`, `em` or `%`.

You could also provide `$k` to the lambda function yourself, for more flexibility:

```
$k = 2;
$output = preg_replace_callback('/([0-9]+)\s*(px|em|%)/i', function($matches) use ($k){
   return ($matches[1] * $k).$matches[2];
}, $input);
```

Comment: +1 Your solution also checks for the context (px|em|%) which is good. The other solution will randomly replace numbers everywhere.

Comment: Might be worth suggesting a method without the use of anonymous functions, or at least mention the PHP requirements etc

Comment: @Ben Swinburne: In the 5.2 days, I would have. But it's not supported anymore. Everybody should be running 5.3. 5.4 is almost out. If you didn't upgrade, you definitely should do it *right now*.

Comment: I use >5.3 but large hosting solutions don't always tend to. For example Rackspace cloud have only just decided to start their upgrade path to 5.3 albeit horrendously late!

Comment: how would this work with decimal numbers? say when font-size:0.25rem;

Answer (score 6):

```
$k = 2;

$f = function ($i) use ($k) {
  return $i[0] * $k;
};

$s = '<div style="padding:10px 15px; font-size:1em ;height:2%;"></div>';
echo preg_replace_callback('/[0-9]+/', $f, $s);
```

This uses anonymous functions available since PHP 5.3. If you want to use it in PHP < 5.3 you have to create a lambda function using [create_function()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php).

Answer (score 5):

```
preg_replace('/\d+/e', '$0 * $k', $input);
```

Comment: +1 That's what I would do most of the times, because I'm not one of those afraid of `eval`, although a little more checking (like I did for `em`, etc.) wouldn't hurt. :)

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know the *e* modifier yet. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do this very easily with a little regex:

```
$k = 2;
$input = '<div style="padding:10px 15px; font-size:1em ;height:2%;"></div>';

$input = preg_replace_callback('/\d+/', function($matches) use ($k) {
    return $matches[0] * $k;
}, $input);
```

This uses the anonymous function syntax introduced in PHP 5.3.  Note that this will alter *all* numbers in the string, not just those in `style` attributes. You'll need to use DOM parsing if you want to avoid that.

You may also find that your styles don't double so easily...

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through the string char by char and have a boolean keeping track of when you find a character that can be interpreted as an int (hint: is_int). If you are in an int keep track of the characters you are traversing and concat them onto a string. As soon as you find a character that is not an int stop concatting onto the string.  Convert this string to a number and multiply by two.  Put it in the right spot in the string (which you know because you marked the beginning and end of the integer).

Or just do what John Kugelman, AndreKR and netcoder did with the regexes.